# generador de codigo aleatorio javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

me encontre este codigo que genera codigos alfanumericos aleatorios, lo estoy usando para enlazar 2 tipos de usuarios, el usuario solo puede generar el codigo una vez y lo guarda en una tabla con id y codigo, luego ese codigo se lo da a otros usuarios para que ellos lo registren y ver unas cosas en conjunto.

Quiero saber como le implemento que no se repitan los codigos que se van guardando en la bd,por el momento los traigo de una base de datos con ajax y quedan  en un array, el generador lo tengo en una funcion asi que no queda front solo es para que vean mas o menos como funciona

```js
       var caracteres = "abcdefghijkmnpqrtuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKMNPQRTUVWXYZ2346789";
       var contraseña = "";
       for (i=0; i<20; i++) contraseña +=caracteres.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*caracteres.length)); 
       console.log(contraseña)
```

Comment: Puedes intentar obtener con un ajax todos los codigos que ya generastes y tienes en tu bd, almacenarlo en un arreglo y cada vez que vasas a generar uno nuevo preguntas que no este en ese arreglo. El ajax lo haces en el onload de la página y las verificaciones en antes de asignarle el valor al campo pass

Comment: si vaz a generar la clave por front es muy vulnerable, alguien puede ver como lo haces e intentarte atacar a tus usuarios por brute force

Comment: Puedes repasar el texto de la pregunta? No me queda claro qué quieres hacer con el código (¿generarlo para mandarlo al servidor?) ni por qué lo quieres generar en el lado del cliente

Comment: Probé con casi todos los navegadores y me funciona perfectamente. Haz un [test de compatibilidad](https://html5test.com/) a tu navegador.

Comment: ya lo edite para los que no entendieron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basado en una [respuesta de SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/424445/4585308), lo que debes hacer es un generador que te permita controlar el valor de la semilla, de esta manera garantizas que no haya duplicados.

Cada que crees tu generador con la misma semilla obtendrás los mismos resultados una y otra vez lo que te permitirá probar que realmente sean diferentes.

Te recomiendo leer acerca de [yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) para evitar llamar desde el inicio el generador y que prosiga donde se había generado el valor anterior, pero eso ya dependerá del stack que estés manejando.

```js
function RNG(seed) {
  // constantes de GCC
  this.m = 0x80000000; // 2**31;
  this.a = 1103515245;
  this.c = 12345;

  this.state = seed ? seed : Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.m - 1));
}
RNG.prototype.nextInt = function() {
  this.state = (this.a * this.state + this.c) % this.m;
  return this.state;
}
RNG.prototype.nextFloat = function() {
  // en el rango [0,1]
  return this.nextInt() / (this.m - 1);
}
RNG.prototype.nextRange = function(start, end) {
  // en el rango [inicio, fin)
  var rangeSize = end - start;
  var randomUnder1 = this.nextInt() / this.m;
  return start + Math.floor(randomUnder1 * rangeSize);
}
RNG.prototype.choice = function(array) {
  return array[this.nextRange(0, array.length)];
}

var contraseñas = [];

var rng = new RNG(20);
var caracteres = "abcdefghijkmnpqrtuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKMNPQRTUVWXYZ2346789".split('');
for (var w = 0; w < 330; w++) {
  var contraseña = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    contraseña += rng.choice(caracteres);
  }
  contraseñas.push(contraseña);
}
console.log(contraseñas);
```